# How to dynamically select columns in pandas based on data in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframes

df1

```
date_time | value1 | column_value
12-Mar-22   17345      17200CE
13-Mar-22   17400      17200PE
....
```

df2

```
date_time | value1 | 17200CE | 17200PE | 17300CE | .......
12-Mar-22   17345    23.3      21.2      24.5
13-Mar-22   17345    24.3      22.2      22.5
```

Now I want add a column in df1 which fetches the value from the column of df2 which corresponds to value in `column_value` column in `df1` and on the same `date_time`.

So finally it would look like

```
date_time | value1 | column_value | mapped_value_result
12-Mar-22   17345    17200CE           23.3
13-Mar-22   17345    17200PE           22.2
```

Comment: Maybe paste a simple  example of `df2` ?

Comment: The `value1` values don't match. Is that a typo, or do you just want to ignore the `value1` column of `df1`?

Comment: @tdy ya value1 column has no major significance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this result is to merge `df1` and `df2` on `date_time` and then use [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```py
md = df2.merge(df1, on='date_time')
df1['mapped_value_result'] = md.values[md.index, md.columns.get_indexer(md.column_values)]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   date_time  value1 column_values  mapped_value_result
0  12-Mar-22   17345       17200CE                 23.3
1  13-Mar-22   17400       17200PE                 22.2
```

Another alternative (also using a merge), is to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to select a value from a `column_values` column in that merged dataframe:

```py
md = df2.merge(df1, on='date_time')
df1['mapped_value_result'] = md.apply(lambda x:x[x['column_values']], axis=1)
```

The output is the same.